# 社内のPDF書類を社外の認証突破者にだけダウンロード可能にさせるツールを開発したい

Tags: oauth

現在、社内で実施した試験結果表を社外のお得意先にお渡しする際結果表の中身は変えず表紙だけお得意先の社名を記載し紙媒体でお渡ししているのですが、毎回表紙の社名だけ変更して中身を一切変更せず試験表を作成する煩わしさに頭を抱えています。
上記の問題解決のため、

**お得意先（ユーザー）を書類ダウンロードサイトにログインさせる

ユーザーがダウンロードリクエストを送る

こちらでリクエスト認証

ダウンロード**

という流れを可能にするツールを開発したいのですが、簡易的でも構いませんので具体的な手法や技術を教えて頂けると幸いです。

Comment: まず、このような「丸投げ質問」はこのサイトでは好まれません。しかも会社の業務ということなので、お金払ってどこかに頼むような内容です。それはさておいて、「表紙を差し替えるのが煩わしい」→「ダウンロードするサイトを作りたい」というのが話がつながりません。ファイルの送付だけに着目すればファイル転送のサービスやアプライアンスがありますが、表紙云々の課題は解決しないので、この点でも回答しにくい質問になってしまっています。

Comment: タイトルの「社外の認証突破者」というと「社外から不正にアクセスしてくる悪意のある者」を想像しますが、違いますよね？　違うのであれば、そのあたり誤解を招かないよう訂正することをお勧めします。

Comment: 「社内で実施した試験結果表を社外のお得意先にお渡しする際結果表の中身は変えず表紙だけお得意先の社名を記載し紙媒体でお渡ししている」という状況がいまいち理解できません。”試験”というのは依頼毎に実施するものではなく既に実施済の試験結果を通知するだけ、という業務なのでしょうか？手入力が面倒なのであればマクロなどの自動化で事足ります。「紙媒体でお渡ししている」ことも面倒なのでしょうか？その場合、「紙媒体」から”電子ファイル”に変更することに問題は生じないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

タイトルの「社外の認証突破者」というのは、社内の PDF 書類作成システムに認証システムが実装されていて、それに登録されているユーザーが正規の手続きで認証を受けて、認証システムで保護されているリソースに社外からアクセスしてくるユーザーと理解して・・・

> お得意先（ユーザー）を書類ダウンロードサイトにログインさせる
> ユーザーがダウンロードリクエストを送る
> こちらでリクエスト認証
> ダウンロード

> という流れを可能にするツールを開発したいのですが、簡易的でも構いませんので具体的な手法や技術を教えて頂けると幸いです。

それから自分が思いつくのは（思い付きレベルですみません）、外部委託するのではなく社内で全部やるとして、

(1) 上記の要件は Web アプリケーションで実現できるので、まず Web アプリケーションに関する基本的な勉強をする。

(2) Web サーバーが必須なので、それをどうできるかを検討する。（OS は何にするのか、社内にサーバーを建てるのか、クラウド上に建てるのかなど）

(3) 上の (1) で勉強した知識をベースにWeb アプリ開発用のフレームワークを決める。認証システムも含まれているものがお勧め。

(4) 開発環境を整えて、ユーザー認証システムを含めた Web アプリを開発する。

(5) 本番用の Web サーバーを建てて、開発した Web アプリをデプロイする。

(6) ユーザーはブラウザを使って Web アプリの PDF 書類作成システムにアクセスし、認証を受けて、PDF ファイルを要求し、ダウンロードする。